# Find data inside the nested ORM in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
class Post(models.Model):
    POST_TYPE =(
        ("video","video"),
        ("pic","pic"),
    )
    upload_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    caption = models.TextField()
    post_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=POST_TYPE)
    media = models.FileField(upload_to='posts/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class PostLikes(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is My **models.py** file and i want to find that if current login user is liked the post or not like this in my templates. I'm doing this in my templates file

```
{% if request.user in i.postlikes_set.all%}
```

but i know it's wrong can anybody solve this problem?
I want to do this in my templates

```
<a class="post-like-btn" href="#" {% if request.user in i.postlikes_set.all%} style="color: #e16a70;" {% else %} style="color:#b2b2b2 !important;" {% endif %}>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the check whether a user likes a `Post` or not is something to be done in a view.

Looking at your post I think you are displaying a list of `Posts` in your template where each item is either liked or not liked by the user. What you could do is annotate each post with this information in the view and then use this information in your template. E.g.

```
#views.py

from django.db.models import OuterRef, Exists

def list_posts(request):
    user = request.user

    my_likes = PostLikes.objects.filter(
        post = OuterRef('pk'),
        like_by = user
    )

    posts = Post.objects.annotate(like_by_user=Exists(my_likes))

    context = {'posts': posts}

    return render(request, 'yourtemplate.html', context)
```

And then in your template you could do

```
<a class="post-like-btn" href="#" {% if i.like_by_user %} style="color: #e16a70;" {% else %} style="color:#b2b2b2 !important;" {% endif %}
```